# Number conversion puzzle: 6373 → 2118, 3496 →?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I am trying to answer this number conversion puzzle - which of the five potential answers is correct, and why?

> 6373 → 2118
> 4728 → 1628
> 5426 → 1220
> 3496 → ?
>
> - A) 1882
> - B) 5412
> - C) 4728
> - D) 9226
> - E) 8224

Source: http://www.admissions.yildiz.edu.tr/images/files/ytuyos2018.pdf

Comment: Hi black and welcome to Puzzling :) I'm glad that you've adopted this neat template for your questions, but I notice that you've posted a couple of very similar-feeling questions in a short space of time, which suggests that you're looking for explanations to a quiz of some kind that you're doing at the moment. This is fine in itself, but can I recommend that for this type of puzzle you look at the digits and see if you can spot a way to derive the numbers on the right with basic mathematical operations like addition, multiplication etc.? You'll probably start spotting the answers yourself :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this is:

> B - 5412

Since:

> If the first number is written as 'abcd', you derive the second by positioning the answers to [c x d] and [a x b] beside each other. Thus, 3496 gives [9x6][3x4], which is 5412 (answer B).